# Finding basis functions

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-transformations, estimation

I have a matrix vector equation of the form $$\mathbf{y}=A\mathbf{x}$$ where $ \mathbf{y}$ is an $M \times 1$ vector which is known and $\mathbf{x}$ is an $N \times 1$ vector which is also known and $M >> N$ (Overdetermined system). I would like to know the columns of $A$ which are the unknown. Are there ways to find them other than by least squares strategy? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to find A. I am aware there is no unique solution. I would like to know is there a way to find the columns of A considering them as a basis function of some space?

Comment: You could always set the first column of $A$ to be $y,$ and the rest of the columns of $A$ to be $0$, in which case $x=e_{1}$ solves the system. If you want something more nontrivial, however, you'd have to impose some additional conditions on $A$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. What if I impose conditions like values in A much be in the interval [-1 ,1]?

Comment: @Oliver 1) this still does not ensure unicity. 2) It even does not ensure existence: consider $y=[100, 100, 100]^\top$ and $x=[1,1]^\top$: no $A$ with coefficients in $[-1,1]$ will suit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments

Comment: I think a nice approach would be to pick some matrix norm, and try to minimize $\|A\|$ subject to $y=Ax.$ In the case that the norm is the Frobenius norm, I believe the minimizer will be $yx^{T}/\|x\|_{2}^{2},$ where that is the squared Euclidean norm of $x$ in the denominator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a different view. Looks interesting. Never thought about it. Will let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is no unique solution to this problem. You've got $M$ equations and $M\times N$ unknowns (the coefficients of $A$). Which solution would you want?

Since it's a linear problem, you could rewrite it in the more conventional form $Ba=b$ where the vector $a$ stacks the $M\times N$ coefficients of $A$ and $B, b$ known.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to find A. I am aware there is no unique solution. I would like to know is there a way to find the columns of A considering them as a basis function of some space?

Comment: @Oliver So that gives you $N-1$ conditions: the columns of $A$ must be linearly independent. OK but you still have to choose $M\times N -M-N+1$ conditions if you want a unique solution.